# Angular Unit Test - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am running Angular unit test with Jasmine/Karma.  Currently getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at ReplicateListComponent_Template (ng:///ReplicateListComponent.js:221:64)
    at executeTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:49857:9)
    at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:49723:13)
    at refreshComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:50894:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:49520:9)
```

Line 221 of ReplicateListComponent.js:

```
        jit___property_12('title',jit___pipeBind1_9(13,28,'upload_replicate_tooltip'))('routerLink',
            jit___pureFunction1_10(32,_c1,ctx.managementConfig.name));
        jit___advance_6(3);
```

`ctx.managementConfig.name` - ctx does not have a variable named `managementConfig` - see screenshot.

[image]

Unit test code:

```
  let component: ReplicateViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReplicateViewComponent>;
  let params: Subject<Params>;
  let queryParams: Subject<Params>;
  let mockManagementService: jasmine.SpyObj<ManagementConfigService>;
  let getManagementConfig: Subject<IManagementConfig>;
  let environmentSwitched: Subject<string>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    params = new Subject<Params>();
    queryParams = new Subject<Params>();
    mockManagementService = jasmine.createSpyObj<ManagementConfigService>([ 'getManagementConfig', 'getCurrentManagementConfig', 'findManagementConfig', 'environmentSwitched' ]);
    getManagementConfig = new Subject<IManagementConfig>();
    environmentSwitched = new Subject<string>();
...
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot({}),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: ':env/replicates', component: DummyComponent },
        ]),
...
      ],
      declarations: [
        ReplicateViewComponent,
...
        ReplicateListComponent,
...
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ManagementConfigService, useValue: mockManagementService },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ACTIVATED_ROUTE },
        { provide: RuntimeConfig, useValue: RUNTIME_CONFIG },
...
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    mockManagementService.getManagementConfig.and.returnValue(getManagementConfig);
    mockManagementService.getCurrentManagementConfig.and.returnValue(RUNTIME_CONFIG.environments[0]);
    mockManagementService.findManagementConfig.and.returnValue(RUNTIME_CONFIG.environments[0]);
    mockManagementService.environmentSwitched.and.returnValue(environmentSwitched);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReplicateViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.list.managementConfig = RUNTIME_CONFIG.environments[0];
    component.list.replicates = REPLICATIONS;
    component.details.replicate = REPLICATIONS[0];

    const router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    router.initialNavigation();

    getManagementConfig.next(RUNTIME_CONFIG.environments[0]);
    environmentSwitched.next(RUNTIME_CONFIG.environments[0].name);
    params.next({ id: '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.list).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.details).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Reason why am I expecting there to be a variable named `managementConfig` :

```
export class ReplicateListComponent extends BaseContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  managementConfig: IManagementConfig;
...
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.add(
      this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.managementConfig = this.managementService.findManagementConfig(params.env);
```

Offending section of ReplicateListComponent's HTML - see the routerLink

```
    <div class="my-auto ml-auto">
      <a data-cy="batchReplicateLink" [title]="'upload_replicate_tooltip' | translate" [routerLink]="[ '/', managementConfig.name, 'replicates', 'batch']" queryParamsHandling="preserve">
        <i class="icons8-sm icons8-Copy"></i>{{ 'replicate_batch_link' | translate }}
      </a>
    </div>
```

ReplicateListComponent.js is very similar to AssetListComponent.js which does not have the error.  As you can see from the screenshot there is a managementConfig within the context of AssetListComponent:

[image]

The routerLink HTML of AssetListComponent is essentially the same:

```
      <a
        data-cy="uploadLink"
        [title]="'upload_asset_tooltip' | translate"
        [routerLink]="[ '/', managementConfig.name, 'assets', 'upload']"
        [queryParamsHandling]="'preserve'"
        *ngIf="managementConfig?.upload"
      >
        <i class="icons8-sm icons8-Upload"></i>{{ 'asset_list_upload_link' | translate }}
      </a>
```

Backend code of AssetListComponent:

```
export class AssetListComponent extends BaseContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  managementConfig: IManagementConfig;
...
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs.add(
      this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.managementConfig = this.managementService.findManagementConfig(params.env);
```

1. What caused the error?
2. What is the fix?
3. Why is the error in ReplicateListComponent but not AssetListComponent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) The error is caused because the first `fixture.detectChanges()` you call, `managementConfig` is undefined at that point in time. Your other component, there is an `*ngIf` where this issue doesn't happen where it will be explained in #3.

2.) The fix would be to hide this HTML until `managementConfig` is truthy:

```
<div class="my-auto ml-auto" *ngIf="managementConfig">
      <a data-cy="batchReplicateLink" [title]="'upload_replicate_tooltip' | translate" [routerLink]="[ '/', managementConfig.name, 'replicates', 'batch']" queryParamsHandling="preserve">
        <i class="icons8-sm icons8-Copy"></i>{{ 'replicate_batch_link' | translate }}
      </a>
    </div>
```

3.) The error is in one place but not the other because in the second one you have an `*ngIf`:

The `*ngIf="managementConfig?.upload"` first checks if `managementConfig` exists (with the question mark) and if it does, does `upload` exist in the object, if it does, go ahead and show this HTML mark up.

If you remove this `*ngIf`, I think the error would happen here as well.

```
<a
        data-cy="uploadLink"
        [title]="'upload_asset_tooltip' | translate"
        [routerLink]="[ '/', managementConfig.name, 'assets', 'upload']"
        [queryParamsHandling]="'preserve'"
        *ngIf="managementConfig?.upload"
      >
        <i class="icons8-sm icons8-Upload"></i>{{ 'asset_list_upload_link' | translate }}
      </a>
```